# Formulario html no envia datos a la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

el problema es que **no se envian los datos** del html a la base de datos y esta todo correctamente,
**Mi archivo php se ejecuta correctamente** (sin errores), con todos los campos completos, al enviar el formulario. los datos no son insertados en mi base de datos. la base de datos esta correctamente configurada: los datos son "**id, first_name, last_name, email, phone y address**" al darle "proceder a pagar" la BD no recibe nada, (creo que esta mal configurado el html)

**Codigo:**

```html
<?php 
// Include the database config file 
require_once 'dbConfig.php'; 
 
// Initialize shopping cart class 
include_once 'Cart.class.php'; 
$cart = new Cart; 
// If the cart is empty, redirect to the products page 
if($cart->total_items() <= 0){ 
    header("Location: index.php"); 
} 
 
// Get posted data from session 
$postData = !empty($_SESSION['postData'])?$_SESSION['postData']:array(); 
unset($_SESSION['postData']); 
 
// Get status message from session 
$sessData = !empty($_SESSION['sessData'])?$_SESSION['sessData']:''; 
if(!empty($sessData['status']['msg'])){ 
    $statusMsg = $sessData['status']['msg']; 
    $statusMsgType = $sessData['status']['type']; 
    unset($_SESSION['sessData']['status']); 
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Pagar | Web Name</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <style>img[alt="www.000webhost.com"]{display:none;}</style>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom style -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <nav style="background: #f2f2f2;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
 <div style="padding: 0 10px 0;width:100%;display:inline-block"> <h4 style="float: left;display: block;"><a style="text-decoration:none;color: black" href="index.php">Web Name </a></h4></div>
 </nav>
 <br>
 <br>
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Pagar</h1>
 <hr>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="checkout">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
                    <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                        <span class="text-muted">Tu Carrito</span><span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill"><?php echo $cart->total_items(); ?></span>
                    </h4>
                    <ul class="list-group mb-3">
                        <?php 
                        if($cart->total_items() > 0){ 
                            //get cart items from session 
                            $cartItems = $cart->contents(); 
                            foreach($cartItems as $item){ 
                        ?>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
                            <div>
                                <h6 class="my-0"><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></h6>
                                <small class="text-muted"><?php echo '$'.$item["price"]; ?> (<?php echo $item["qty"]; ?>)</small>
                            </div>
                            <span class="text-muted"><?php echo '$'.$item["subtotal"]; ?></span>
                        </li>
                        <?php } } ?>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                            <span>Total (ARS)</span>
                            <strong><?php echo '$'.$cart->total(); ?></strong>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-block btn-info">Añadir Mas Productos</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
                    <h4 class="mb-3">Informacion De Contacto</h4>
                    <form method="post" action="cartAction.php">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                <label for="first_name">Nombre Completo</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['first_name'])?$postData['first_name']:''; ?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">Apellido
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['last_name'])?$postData['last_name']:''; ?>" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['email'])?$postData['email']:''; ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="phone">Telefono</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['phone'])?$postData['phone']:''; ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="last_name">Direccion</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="<?php echo !empty($postData['address'])?$postData['address']:''; ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="placeOrder"/>
                        <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="checkoutsubmit" value="Proceder a Pagar">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <footer style="width: 100%;text-align: center;color: black;background: #f2f2f2;padding: 10px 0 10px"><h6>Copyright ©2020 All rights reserved | by <a style="text-decoration:none;color: deepskyblue" href="">Web creator</a></h6></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

hola, el problema es que **no se envian los datos** del html a la base de datos y esta todo correctamente,
**Mi archivo php se ejecuta correctamente** (sin errores), con todos los campos completos, al enviar el formulario. los datos no son insertados en mi base de datos. la base de datos esta correctamente configurada: los datos son "**id, first_name, last_name, email, phone y address**" al darle "proceder a pagar" la BD no recibe nada, (creo que esta mal configurado el html)

Comment: Cuando mandas datos desde un formulario tienes que recuperarlos usando la superglobal según el método que hayas indicado en el `form`. En este caso el método de tu formulario es `POST`, pero no veo que en el servidor uses `$_POST["last_name"]`, `$_POST["email"]`, etc, para recuperar los datos posteados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habría que ver el código del cartAction.php

Como dice un comentario anterior, debes recibir las variables de la forma $_POST["last_name"], $_POST["email"] para luego insertarlas en la base de datos, ya que el formulario tiene método post.